# Parallel Programming C# - TPL - Update Shared Variable & Suggestions

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, thread-safety, task-parallel-library

I am new to Parallel Programming and infact this is the first time I am trying it. I am currently doing a project in .NET 4 and prefer to do have 4 or 5 parallel executions.

I see some options. There is `Task.Factory.StartNew` `Parallel.For` `Parallel.ForEach` etc.

What I am going to do is post to a web-site and fetch the responses for about 200 URLs.

When I use `Parallel.ForEach` I didn't find a way to control the number of threads and the application went using 130+ threads and the website went unresponsive :)

I am interested in using `Task.Factory.StartNew` within a for loop and divide the URLs in to 4 or 5 tasks.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    List<string> UrlForTask = GetUrlsForTask(i,5); //Lets say will return some thing like 1 of 5 of the list of URLs
    int j = i;
    var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        List<PageSummary> t = GetSummary(UrlForTask);
        Summary.AddRange(t); //Summary is a public variable
    }
    tasks.Add(t);
}
```

I believe that these Tasks kind of boil down to threads. So if I make `Summary` a `List<PageSummary>` will it be kind of thread safe (I understand there are issues accessing a shared variable by multiple threads)?

Is this where we should use `ConcurrentQueue<T>` ?

Do you know of a good resource that helps to learn about accessing and updating a shared variable by multiple tasks etc?

What is the best way I could use for this type of task as you may think ?

Comment: Use `.AsParallel.SelectMany()` instead of the entire loop.

Comment: @SLaks, Do you mean instead of `Parallel.Foreach` use some thing like `Summary = AllUrls.AsParallel().SelectMany( i => GetSummary(i) ).ToList()` ?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @SLaks: Wow, that is some cool way to solve that type of problem. But as per using `ParallelOptions` for the `Parallel.ForEach`, is there an ability to control the parallelism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Parallel.ForEach` has overloads that take a `ParallelOptions` instance. The `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property of that class is what you need to use.

```
List<MyRequest> requests = ...;
BlockingCollection<MyResponse> responses = ...;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Parallel.ForEach(
        requests,
        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
        request => responses.Add(MyDownload(request)));
    responses.CompleteAdding();
});

foreach (var response in responses.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    Console.WriteLine(response.MyMessage);
}
```

Comment: I went through the MSDN but missed that, thanks for pointing it out... I have a question, you are using `BlockingCollection` and I see it is a thread safe collection. If I use a `list<>` it might cause me problems isn't it?

Comment: The `responses.Add` calls are being made concurrently, so a `List` would break if used this way. You could alternatively use a `List<MyResponse> responses` and then `lock(responses) { responses.Add(...); }` but the `BlockingCollection` does the job for you already.